# How to add a new column in Microsoft Project from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm writing a Sub in Excel right now with VBA. I've successfully opened a MS Project project. Now, I want to add a new column in the MS Project file via Excel VBA. How do I do this?

'''vba

```
Dim MSProject As MSProject.Application
Dim project As MSProject.project

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
wb.Activate
ws.Select

' Open Microsoft Project project
Set MSProject = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
With MSProject
    .FileOpen "test.mpp"
    .Application.Visible = True
End With

Set project = MSProject.ActiveProject

' Add column in Project (this syntax does not work)
MSProject.TableEditEx(Name:="test.mpp", TaskTable:=True, _NewFieldName:="JIRA Issue Key", Title:="JIRA Issue Key", Width:=15, _ShowInMenu:=True, _ColumnPosition:=1)
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `MSProject` as a variable name as it the name of the library. Same for `project`. Typical variable names would be something like `prjApp` and `prj`.
2. Do you have an enterprise field named "JIRA Issue Key"? The field name must be a valid, existing field.
3. The `Name` argument in the `TableEditEx` refers to the name of the table, not the project.
4. After editing the table, you need to apply changes with `TableApply`

Here's how the code should look to add an existing field to the default table (Entry) in the default view (Gantt Chart):

```
prjApp.TableEditEx Name:="Entry", TaskTable:=True, NewFieldName:="Text1", Title:="Custom title here", Width:=15, ShowInMenu:=True, ColumnPosition:=1
prjApp.TableApply "Entry"
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.tableeditex) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your suggestions but now I am getting a Run-time error '1004'. The view or report cannot be displayed because the table "test.mpp" on which it is based has been deleted. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The `Name` argument should be the name of a ***table***, not the project name, not the view name. Typically, this is 'Entry' for a Gantt Chart view. Edit the view to see the name of the table is uses (View ribbon, Other Views, More Views..., find the view you want and click Edit.)